# I can't seem to get any jQuery events to work on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

I am having problems getting anything jQuery to work on my page. It is not that it isn't working correctly, just that it doesn't seem to be doing ANYTHING....and I have searched for a week all over trying to find an answer or reason why, and it isn't turning anything up so I am to the point where I am going to ask a question to you all on here, and hope I can get some help. My html and js files are pasted here:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page!</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>Welcome to my site!</header>
        <nav>
            <a href="i310index.html"> About Me |</a>
            <a href="i310interests.html">My Interests |</a>
            <a href="i310resume.html">Resume |</a>
            <a href="i310contact.html">Contact Me</a>
        </nav>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Hello there, my name is Amanda and I'm a fifth year senior here at IU. I have been spent the semester learning jQuery for INFO-I 310 to make this website. It has been difficult to learn, but it has also been really interesting!
                <br /> <br />
                I will be graduating from IU this May (2014) with a Bachelor's degree in Informatics, as well as a cognate and minor in Pyschology. I would love to find a career after graduation where I can use the technology skills I have learned to help others. While I will be sad to leave IU, I am also excited about what will come in the future!</p>
            </div>
    </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery File**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".content" ).resizable({ animate: true });
});
```

I just don't know where else to look at this point and am going out of my mind trying to figure out why it won't do anything, so any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!! Thanks so much!! :)

Comment: The problem in your jquery files check whether its loading or not

Comment: second jquery is not loading in your file check http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow :) Is your CSS really relevant here? If not, you should remove it from the question.

Comment: Did you check the browser error console or the debug console for errors?  That should be one of the first places you look for what might be going wrong.

Comment: there IS an error in your console. that should have been your first stop, not stackoverflow.

Comment: Is `http:` not needed before `//ajax.googleapis.com....` ?

Comment: Please use this jquery file only, <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Kevin, I did check that, but I don't understand what it wrong with it, I can't figure it out. I've tried everything I could think of before I came to this site, so don't tell me I didn't. :(

Answer (score 0):

Link problem. Replace this link

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `jquery ui` url is not working use,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

in place of

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5v4YJ/)

Comment: Check your `script.js` is loaded or not, or try your `script code` in the same page.

Comment: Do you mean adding it like this: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My Page!</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".content" ).resizable({ animate: true });
   });
  </script>

Comment: @amelrich Your script not works **Replace** `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` **BY**
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`